# IntegrityError: FK field (user_id) remains "null" despite form_valid() override

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

The user should be able to log an activity into the Activity_Log model but the CreateView form must automatically fill the user_id from the current logged-in user.

I have extended the django *auth_user* table on a OnetoOne relationship into another model named Profile (*users-profile*). *user_id* is a ForeignKey field automatically added to my Profile model (I can see it in MySQL WorkBench) and is the PrimaryKey in auth_user model.

**However, I'm getting an IntegrityError (1048: 'user_id' cannot be 'null'), despite using *def form_valid(self, form)* override in LogCreateView.** I've tried several variants of form_valid() from StackOverflow examples but to no avail.

My POST variables are all correct inputs for the other fields correctly taken from the form i.e. *'projectrowid', 'activityid', 'startdatetime', 'enddatetime', 'comments'*, but the user_id is not being passed along with the POST variables to the Activity_Log model.

Any advice on how to correctly override def form_valid() would be really appreciated!

**views.py - LogCreateView**

```py
class LogCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Activity_Log
    fields = ['projectrowid', 'activityid', 'startdatetime', 'enddatetime', 'comments']

    def get_template_names(self):
        if self.request.user.is_superuser:
            template_name = 'Administrator/activity_log_form.html'
            return template_name
        else:
            template_name = 'Staff/activity_log_form.html'
            return template_name

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.user_id = self.request.user.id
        return super(LogCreateView, self).form_valid(form)
```

**models.py - ActivityLog model**

```py
class Activity_Log(models.Model):
    logentryid = models.AutoField(db_column='logEntryID', primary_key=True)  
    activityid = models.ForeignKey('Activity_Type', models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='activityID', verbose_name= _('Activity ID'))
    projectrowid = models.ForeignKey('Project', models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='projectRowID',verbose_name= _('Project Name'))
    staffrowid = models.ForeignKey('users.Profile', on_delete=models.CASCADE, db_column='user_id',
                                   verbose_name=_('Staff Alias'))

    startdatetime = models.DateTimeField(db_column='startDateTime', default=datetime.datetime.now(), verbose_name= _('Activity Start (Date and Time: yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss)'))
    enddatetime = models.DateTimeField(db_column='endDateTime', default=datetime.datetime.now(), verbose_name= _('Activity End (Date and Time: yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss)'))
    comments = models.CharField(max_length=150)
```

**users\models.py - Profile model**

```py
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    stafftypeid = models.ForeignKey('Administrator.Staff_Type', models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='staffTypeID')
    employeeid = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    alias = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    department = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    organization = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    fte = models.DecimalField(max_digits=4, decimal_places=1, default=Decimal(100.0))

    class Meta:
        unique_together = [('alias',), ('employeeid',)]
        db_table = 'users-profile'
```

Comment: Normally in Django, you don't include `id` in foreign key names. Then `activity.staffrow` will be the related object, and `activity.staffrow_id` is its id. At the moment, `activity.staffrowid` is the object, and `activity.staffrowid_id` is its id, which is a bit confusing.

Comment: Do you really want `unique_together = [('alias',), ('employeeid',)]`? I would have expected to see `unique_together = [('alias', 'employeeid')]`, or `unique_together = ['alias', 'employeeid']`.

Comment: Thank you for raising the typo on "unique_together"! 

I've now made it clear in the field attributes of the model that these should be set to unique=True.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your foreign key to the `Profile` model is `Activity_Log.staffrowid`.

That means you should be setting `form.instance.staffrowid` if you use a model instance, or `form.instance.staffrowid_id` if you use the id.

```
form.instance.staffrowid = self.request.user.profile
```

Note that since `staffrowid` is a foreign key to `Profile`, I've used `self.request.user.profile` instead of `self.request.user`. You might need code to handle the case where a profile doesn't exist for the user.

Comment: Thank you - this worked perfectly. I've tried to ensure that upon registration of a new User, the relevant fields in the Profile model are also validly input. As far as I can tell in my code, there should be no mismatch between the two models.

Regarding the